# org.apache.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered " "[" "[ "

Tags: jsf-2, el

i have a util **el** method that gets an object in a list with index

```
public static Object get(List list, Integer index) {
        return list.get(index);
    }
```

and i am calling this method in the **xhtml** page to get the name of first element in list
as follows:

```
<span>#{[utils:get(myBean.myList,1)].name}</span>
```

but above expression gives me the following exception:

```
org.apache.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered " "[" "[ "" at line 1, column 3.
Was expecting one of:
    <INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
    <FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL> ...
    <STRING_LITERAL> ...
    "true" ...
    "false" ...
    "null" ...
    "(" ...
    "!" ...
    "not" ...
    "empty" ...
    "-" ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
```

any ideas why ?

Comment: Yes; `"["` aren't allowed there; parens are, if you're trying to scope what `.name` is being applied to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because it's invalid syntax. Valid EL syntax is described in the [EL specification document](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/index.html). The brace notation `[]` is used to get an list or array item by index and to dynamically resolve keys of a map. The following is valid syntax in your case:

```
<span>#{utils:get(myBean.myList,1).name}</span>
```

However, the custom function is unnecessary. Just use the following syntax:

```
<span>#{myBean.myList[1].name}</span>
```

Comment: how to iterate on that list in JS, please see my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644116/iterate-on-list-in-a-backing-bean-with-javascript