# Iterate over a list from backing bean in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, el

I have a list of objects in backing bean
and I would like to iterate over it in JavaScript,
so I tried the following:

```
<script>
    //<![CDATA[
    var length = #{fn:length(myBean.myList)};

    for (i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
        var value = '#{myBean.myList[i].id}';
        var label = '#{myBean.myList[i].firstName}';
        alert(value);
        alert(label);
    }
    //]]>
</script>
```

I get no errors in console, but it shows empty alerts. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: I am not a java expert, but I guess `#` things are meant to be executed on the server side, while your loop and its `i` variable is on the client.

Comment: el can be executed in JS with no problems, the issue is with the loop variable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to convert it to an array of JS objects first. Provided that `id` is numeric, here's how:

```js
var users = [
  <ui:repeat value="#{bean.users}" var="user" varStatus="loop">
    { id: #{user.id}, firstName: "#{user.firstName}" }#{loop.last ? '' : ','}
  </ui:repeat>
];

for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    alert(user.id);
    alert(user.firstName);
}
```

This will only fail if the user name contains a newline (double quotes are already escaped by JSF). Consider explicitly escaping JS as per [Escape JavaScript in Expression Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617155/escape-javascript-in-expression-language/)

Better way is to let JSF (or preferably, some web service, e.g. JAX-RS, upon an ajax request) return it in [JSON](http://json.org) format already by using a JSON parser/formatter like [Google Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), so that you can just do:

```js
var users = #{bean.usersAsJson};

for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    alert(user.id);
    alert(user.firstName);
}
```

with (assuming that you're using Gson):

```
public String getUsersAsJson() {
    return new Gson().toJson(users);
}
```

Please also note that you should use `i < length` not `i <= length`. Please also note that `users` is more self-documenting than `myList`.

Comment: console.log(#{bean.property}); just appears as console.log() when I debug javaScript, the same thing with ui:repeat, or c:foreach, it shows var users = [ ].     It's not populating the variables.

Comment: This is not caused by beans being called in a piece of text in a Facelet which happens to represent JavaScript code.

Comment: I don't understand, is that a question? I'm calling it inside a <ui:define name="javascript">
  <script type="text/javascript"> inside a .JSP page, yes.

Comment: You're using Facelets tags in a JSP page? You've definitely a different problem not related to the question currently asked.

Comment: Yes, but there are other working richFaces components in this page like <rich:toolBarGroup and <a4j:poll. I even tried with <a4j:repeat but the same thing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error and I resolved it by using
 `"&lt;"`   instead of < in for loop