# How to Pass JSF Bean data to JavaScript Function?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I am passing data with the below code:

```
<p:poll interval="3" listener="#{chartController.loadChartData}" oncomplete="renderChart('container','area','Sample Chart', '#{chartController.chartData}', '#{chartController.categories}');" 
                      id="chartvalue_btn" update="textID" />
```

But when I checked null value is passed in JavaScript function while I checked bean variable initialized with values. Am I doing something wrong here?
ANd my bean is

```
package com.bchetty.charts.controller;

import com.bchetty.charts.model.Series;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

/**
 * Chart Controller
 */
@ManagedBean(name="chartController")
@SessionScoped
public class ChartController {
    private String chartData;
    private String categories;
    private List<String> categoryList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<Long> heapSizeList = new ArrayList<Long>();
    private List<Long> usedHeapSizeList = new ArrayList<Long>();
    SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");//dd/MM/yyyy
    private static final long MB = 1024*1024;
    int index = 0;
    private Long[] longs;

    /**
     * Load Chart Data
     */
    public void loadChartData() {
        if(heapSizeList.size() > 10) {
            heapSizeList.remove(0);
            usedHeapSizeList.remove(0);
            categoryList.remove(0);
        }
        List<Series> series = new ArrayList<Series>();

        malloc();
        long heapSize = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
        heapSizeList.add(heapSize/MB);
        usedHeapSizeList.add((heapSize - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory())/MB);

        series.add(new Series("Heap Size", heapSizeList));
        series.add(new Series("Used Heap", usedHeapSizeList));

        setChartData(new Gson().toJson(series));

        categoryList.add(sdfDate.format(new Date()));
        System.out.println(categoryList);

        setCategories(new Gson().toJson(categoryList));
    }

    /**
     * @return the chartData
     */
    public String getChartData() {
        return chartData;
    }

    /**
     * @param chartData the chartData to set
     */
    public void setChartData(String chartData) {
        this.chartData = chartData;
    }

    /**
     * @return the categories
     */
    public String getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    /**
     * @param categories the categories to set
     */
    public void setCategories(String categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    private void malloc() {
        if(index%2 == 0) {
            longs = new Long[100000];
            for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
                longs[i] = Long.valueOf(i);
            }
        } else {
            longs = null;
        }
        index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822484/el-expression-inside-pcommandbutton-onclick-does-not-update-re-render-on-ajax-r

Comment: @alonso its not what i am looking for in my case its empty

Comment: what's the scope of your bean? with the information you gave your problem seems related to the one linked in my previous comment as primefaces doesn't evaluates the expression for `on*` attributes on a per-request basis.

Comment: `#{chartController.chartData}` and `#{chartController.categories}` seem type of java collections. This not the way to access collection types in javascript. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644116/iterate-on-list-in-a-backing-bean-with-javascript

Comment: its already a GSON object

Comment: @askkuber sill some information missing, what is the scope of your bean? did you tried to use the `ViewScoped` annotation (or any other means to place the bean into the view scope)? Also, some snippets of the actual bean would help

Comment: @AlonsoDominguez added bean also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the arguments of the `oncomplete`-function are only updated when the view is entered. The arguments are not automatically updated when the value of the properties on the bean have changed. So as `chartController.chartData` is initially not instanciated it is `null` when the page is rendered and remains `null` until you manually refresh the whole page.

To fix this issue I would recommend you to use the [Primefaces RequestContext](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/requestContext.jsf) and add the `chartData` everytime `loadChartData` is called as a callback param.
I.e. add the following to the and of `loadChartData`:

```
public void loadChartData() {
    ...
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.addCallbackParam("chartData", chartData);
    context.addCallbackParam("categories", categories);
}
```

And in the UI define the `p:poll` as follows:

```
<p:poll interval="3" listener="#{chartController.loadChartData}"
    oncomplete="renderChart('container','area','Sample Chart', args.chartData, args.categories);"
    id="chartvalue_btn" update="textID" />
```

If this is no option for you, because you are using `loadChartData` anywhere else, wrap the call of `loadChartData` with the `addCallbackParam` stuff in another method and specify this method as listener of the `p:poll`.

Comment: after updating with ur changes nothing happening why you changes  oncomplete JavaScript called

Comment: I think i have to use <p:poll interval="3" listener="#{chartController.loadChartData}"
    oncomplete=" renderChart('container','area','Sample Chart', args.chartData, args.categories);"
    id="chartvalue_btn"   />

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happening"? Are the values still `null`? You have to change the `oncomplete`-function to handle the arguments in the right way.

Comment: Delete this function(xhr, status, args)